# Android Java, onfinish(); moves me in an activity

Tags: java, android

I have three activities (`a`, `b`, `c`).

**Activity `a`**
 - has one button for activity `b` and one button to close the app (by calling `onfinish()`).
 - is the main activity, which runs `b`.
**Activity `b`**
 - is the middle one which runs `c`.

After clicking on a back button that I placed in the header of activity `c`,  and then clicking on the button of the a activity to close the app, I am returned to activity `c`. This is not the behavior I expected, any ideas about what is happening?

Further information:

1. activity `c` has `onResume()` because I also have an activity `d`. so when I click back button of activity `d`, it returns to activity `c`.
2. so long as I don't run the activity `c`, the close button works as expected.

Comment: Seems like you got a bad understanding of basic android navigation and activity/intents: an Android application does not really "closes", your just terminate an `Activity` using `finish()` and not `onfinish()`, the back button simply finishes the current `Activity` and brings back the last one. Also check your `Intent` flags.

Comment: I know very well that the app is still running even after 'closing' it. Also onfinish() was a typo, otherwise I'dnt make this question. Anjali with his answer shows how to finish my application, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

For going previous activity just call

```
finish() ;
```

at back button  of any activity .don't  do this

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and from exiting the application use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), a.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I've used finish(); on activity c too and now it gets me to activity b, lol.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() or UrActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Where at ? activity a closebutton or ?

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried it out yet. I'll try it in 30-60 minutes and I'll let you know! (if it works ull get my tick :P)